# Bootstrap with rowspan

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabular

I've been playing with Bootstrap to try and get a structure like below:

[image: Table]

I've tried using rowspan, but this doesn't give me a nice HTML structure that will easy to generate from PHP.

Should I be using tables with rowspan for this? Or is there a better solution using divs?

Comment: If that table is a real table you'd better to implement it as an HTML table not divs. So, I suggest you to deal with PHP side of generating it. Why it's not easy?

Comment: You can use ul li instead of div each li have three div using table cell and table row you can create structure like this

Comment: It's not too difficult, but obviously you have to have a tr with the rowspan row, then another tr without for process 2, then another tr for process 3. You essentially end up with 'header tr' rows, it's not too difficult but I thought I'd ask in case there was an obvious way to do it with bootstrap I couldn't find.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this would be hard to generate with PHP. Since you know the number of processes per server, you can just echo a td with rowspan="this number" when $process==1, and not echo it when $process>1.